# Which is better to use for XMPP framework OR CocoaAsyncSocket for real time communication for an iOS application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, xmppframework, cocoaasyncsocket

I want to implement real time communication(like chat) in my app.
I am confuse what should be used either XMPP framework or CocoaAsyncSocket ?

As CocoaAsyncSocket works is mention here https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket/blob/master/README.markdown In same manner how XMPP works ?
Please explain.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XMPP protocol is the standard protocol for real time chat purpose,Many apps on app store uses this protocol for chatting

With XMPP protocol you can do many things like:
Single user chat
Multi user chat
Voice chat,video chat
offline messages,save history,message logging ,presence notifications etc..

Benifit of XMPP protocol :-

1)XMPP has been designed to send all messages in real-time using a very efficient push mechanism

2)XMPP  tackles security issues that are not straight forward to solve in the web world. Since all traffic is routed through the server and the identity of that server can be validated with signatures issued by Certified Authorities, end users do not need to worry about complex things like signatures to establish secure communication

3)XMPP can also be used for real time chat with Facebook users and gtalk users

check out these links for more information:-

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Messaging_and_Presence_Protocol

http://xmpp.org/

Comment: Hey piyush i am able to do instant chatting but how to send files in xmpp. For now i have converted the image,video to base64 and sending to other peer point as a string with custom xml. But i want to send it as a file because i don't get progress status while sending video and image also the two points gets disconnected when i send big video

Comment: Hey Piyushbhai
Do you have any idea how to implement Voice and Video in XMPP ??

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework

how to compile is on this link.

https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/wiki/GettingStarted_iOS

Download XMPP framework from above links.In that there is a folder Xcode containing two applications,one for desktop and other one for IPhone.

Run the iPhone application,it display a login page and you have to enter gmail user name and password and it also work for Facebook but that is some what is difficult..

I hope this answer useful to you...